# onReceive called twice in BroadcastReceiver for Network Listener in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

Why on receive called twice, when Network state changed.

Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="tv.meterreading.network.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276032/connectivity-action-intent-received-twice-when-wifi-connected , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412714/broadcastreceiver-receives-multiple-identical-messages-for-one-event

Answer (score -1):

Receiving multiple broadcast is a device specific problem. Some phones just send one broadcast while other send 2 or 3. But there is a work around:

Assuming you get the disconnect message when the wifi is disconnected, I would guess the first one is the correct one and the other 2 are just echoes for some reason.

To know that the message has been called, you could have a static boolean that gets toggled between connect and disconnect and only call your sub-routines when you receive a connection and the boolean is true. Something like:

public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static boolean firstConnect = true;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetInfo != null) {
        if(firstConnect) { 
            // do subroutines here
            firstConnect = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        firstConnect= true;
    }
}
```

}