# BroadcastReceiver for WALLPAPER_CHANGED calls onReceive() multiple times : Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-wallpaper

I have a BroadcastReceiver and declared it like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.services.Receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the receiver is:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
{
    change_wallpepar.myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("MAYUR", "<< wallpepar changed >>");
            if (change_wallpepar.myPrefs.getLong("temp_for_change", 1) == 0)
            {
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, change_wallpepar.class));
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = change_wallpepar.myPrefs.edit();
                e.putLong("temp_for_change", 0);
                e.commit();
            }
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

When I change the wallpaper here it should be called once. It is really working as by my expectations for a while, after some minutes it calls `onreceive()` multiple (10-18) times, even though the change in wallpaper is done once. Even more strange about this is that it is working fine on a Samsung Galaxy tablet version 4.4.2, but not working on Motorola (Moto E 4.4.4).

My service:

```
public class change_wallpepar extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        mytimer = new Timer();
        wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(change_wallpepar.this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        intervall = myPrefs.getLong("someValue", 60000);

        path_of_wallpepar.clear();
        path_of_wallpepar.add("" + "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/WallpeparAppHistoryPhotos/514.jpg");
        path_of_wallpepar.add("" + "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/WallpeparAppHistoryPhotos/513.jpg");

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOption = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(change_wallpepar.this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOption).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

        mytimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                try
                {
                    wpm.setBitmap(ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("file://" + path_of_wallpepar.get(temper)));

                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                temper++;

                if (temper == path_of_wallpepar.size())
                    temper = 0;

                SharedPreferences.Editor e = change_wallpepar.myPrefs.edit();
                e.putLong("temp_for_change", 1);
                e.commit();

                Log.e("MAYUR", "wallpepar seted");

            }
        }, 0, intervall);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(1000);
        mytimer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

My Logcat output is:

```
## Logcat ##
04-16 11:06:30.654: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:06:34.636: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:06:59.584: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:07:03.551: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:07:30.078: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:07:33.979: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:07:59.433: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:08:03.340: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:08:30.029: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:08:33.933: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:08:59.481: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:09:03.383: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:09:30.066: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:09:33.966: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:09:59.448: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:10:03.353: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:10:30.049: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:10:33.955: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:10:59.455: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:11:03.350: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:11:30.182: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:11:34.177: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:11:59.406: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:12:03.315: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:30.025: E/MAYUR(3405): wallpepar seted
04-16 11:12:33.929: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:34.103: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:34.298: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:34.497: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:34.676: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:34.854: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.022: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.190: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.355: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.522: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.683: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:35.852: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:36.023: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:36.187: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:36.350: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
04-16 11:12:36.513: D/MAYUR(3405): << wallpepar changed >>
```

Comment: Note that if you target API 26 and above, you can't use this in the manifest. Need to register. Proof: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repeated `WALLPAPER_CHANGED` calls are caused by smaller Android devices running crop-scale cycles on the image to fit the screen. This is observed in the [AOSP code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/WallpaperManager.java). You're less likely to see this behavior when the screen ratio fits or is bigger than the image, hence why the tablet doesn't exhibit this behavior.

You can fix this problem by double-checking for signs of the unwanted behavior:

```
long lastExec = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
{
    change_wallpepar.myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastExec>1000)
          {
            Log.d("MAYUR", "<< wallpepar changed >>");
            if (change_wallpepar.myPrefs.getLong("temp_for_change", 1) == 0)
            {
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, change_wallpepar.class));
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = change_wallpepar.myPrefs.edit();
                e.putLong("temp_for_change", 0);
                e.commit();
            }
          }
          lastExec = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens on some devices but it would seem to me to most likely be a problem with that specific device. Whilst I cannot resolve that issue, potentially you could hold a variable that is toggled once your listener is hit and reset after a period of time. This will thus cause your listener to ignore future calls for a short period of time.. think of it like flood protection.

I know that doesn't resolve your actual issue but I hope it will provide a suitable workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Most possibly a device specific problem.

In general using a flag I guess is the [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8413512/1081340) solution

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
{
     private static boolean firstReceive = true;
    change_wallpepar.myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
           if(firstReceive){
            Log.d("MAYUR", "<< wallpepar changed >>");
            if (change_wallpepar.myPrefs.getLong("temp_for_change", 1) == 0)
            {
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, change_wallpepar.class));
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = change_wallpepar.myPrefs.edit();
                e.putLong("temp_for_change", 0);
                e.commit();
            }
        }
   ///CHANGE firstReceive BASED ON EITHER TIME SINCE LAST WALLPAPER CHANGE
   ///OR ANY OTHER PARAMETER THAT SUITS YOUR REQUIREMENT
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

**Note that I haven't reset the flag again in the Loop**, you should probably do it **after a certain amount of time since last change** OR **save some current wallpaper identifier in shared pref and match against that and set the flag** etc., based on your requirement

The idea is to workaround the issue, so you get over the false positives and actually change for real `wallpaper_change` calls. This is a `Workaround` and not an actual solution to why the problem exists.

Comment: firstReceive = false; not done anywhere so i think its not useful in my que.

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned in my answer. It's upto you to reset it correctly so you don't allow false positives but also don't screen out actual wall paper changes