# BroadcastReceiver for Internet checking

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have Broadcast Receiver for doing Internet checking. Every time device is not connected with Internet, always getting 2 output. I just want one output.

---

### BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if (!isConnected){
        Log.i("INTERNET","------------------------- not connect");
    }
}
```

}

---

### And this is the output

```
12659-12659 I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12659-12659 I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12659-12701 V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
12659-12701 V/RenderScript: 0xb8116c40 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
12659-12659 I/INTERNET: ------------------------- not connect
12659-12659 I/INTERNET: ------------------------- not connect
```

Comment: Have you add permission internet in manifest?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413512/5545429)

Comment: Where do you register the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: One is called for wifi and one is called for mobile data

Comment: yes, I have add the permission and receiver action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

create one class

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

public ConnectivityReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
        connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
    }
}

public static boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager
            cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}


public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
}
```

}

**create one another class**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication mInstance;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
    ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
}
```

}

**add permisiion in maenfiest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**and this **

**

**and dont forget to add this in manifiest**

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.ncrypted.redfox.Utils.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**now call the where you want to check internet like this**

implement this in your activity

```
 ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener

 @Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    showSnack(isConnected);
}
 private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    if (isConnected) {
        getUserStatus();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.str_internet_err), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[**for more information please follow this link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/)

Comment: Hei @nilesh-rathod but still double output with this.... how can be single?

Comment: I try to change snackbar with alertdialog, and after no connection, alertdialog show twice at the same time

Comment: private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    if (isConnected) {
        getUserStatus();
    } else {
        show here alertdialog
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144562/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-angger-prasetyo).

Answer (score 0):

You can check Network availability without Broadcast Receiver.

```
public class ConnectivityUtils {
private final Activity mActivity;

public ConnectivityUtils(Activity mActivity) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}

public  boolean getConnectivityStatus() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return null != activeNetwork;
}
}
```

Add in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```